# Django Messaging Framework in the save() function

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-messages

I am checking if a model instance already exists and if does I want to send a message saying "Name already exists". As there is not request in def save(), is there any other way to send a message via Django message framework or something else??

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.name = self.name
    if Name.names.name_exists(self.name):
        message = "You already have this name!" # want to send this message
        print("not created")
    else:
        print("created")
        super(Name, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I think that you don't need to check if a object name exist by override the save method. Instead, you can check it before create a new object like : `myObject = Object.objects.get(name=name_to_check)` if the object exist then send a message with django message (`from django.contrib import messages`). If not create the new object.

Comment: Overriding the save method is not the best practice you mean?

Comment: For this specific goal, yes overriding the save method is not the best idea (i think). You want check if object exist before save. Then do it before call `.save()` on your `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use django messages framework with `messages.warning(request, 'Object already exists.')` instead of that `print` statement and depending on your logic instead of warning message you can send success or info messages. In your template you can use;

```py
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

But this option will be available for your view layer not in model layer. Don't forget to checkout [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/#module-django.contrib.messages).

Comment: Thanks but But save method does not have request right?

Comment: Yes like I said you can use messages framework in your view not in `save`  method of your object. Because the goal in the messages framework is sending a text to your template and render it so you can send a message to user :)